# Loading App using iOS simulator

Tags: ios

Using the iOS Simulator I cannot get passed clicking the app, opening the first screen (for maybe 1 sec), and then reverting back to the homepage. The program builds and runs successfully however, once I get to the homepage, click the app, it only opens for maybe a second, and then closes. Can you fill me in on what I need to do to run the app through its entirety? (all the screens)

Comment: It sounds like the app is crashing. What does it say in the debugger?

Comment: There aren't any comments in the debugger. The app builds and runs properly, however once I get to the simulator the app never stays open. All other apps in the simulator run except mine lol. It opens for a second then closes to the homepage. What do I need to do?

Comment: Do I need to add code to viewDidLoad in order for the app to avoid crashing? If so, what?